# Awk or Perl solution to delete lines with incomplete data

Tags: perl, awk

Is there an Awk or Perl one-liner that can remove all rows that do not have complete data. I find myself frequently needing something like this. For example, I currently have a tab-delimited file that looks like this:

```
1    asdf    2
9    asdx    4
3    ddaf    6
5            4
2    awer    4
```

How can a line that does not have a value in field 2 be removed?

How could a line that does not have a value in one of ANY field be removed?

I was trying to do something like this:

```
awk -F"\t" '{if ($2 != ''){print $0}}' 1.txt > 2.txt
```

Thanks.

Comment: Take care when using \ characters in shell commands.  In this case the "\t" would have been escaped you the shell, so you wouldn't actually have used TAB as field separator.  If you use `-F'\t'` then your one liner will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In awk, if you know that every row should have exactly 3 elements:

```
awk -F'\t+' 'NF == 3' INFILE > OUTFILE
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the NF variable. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This won't work when the file contains values that have spaces.

Comment: Hmmm. I tried this but awk is reading the white-space between the tab characters as a field. Any suggestions?

Comment: Trouble is, it still doesn't work as an empty field (`5\t\t4`) would mean that NF is 3, so the solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I would just look for consecutive tabs, or a leading or trailing tab:

```
perl -ne 'next if /\t\t/ or /^\t/ or /\t$/; print' tabfile
```

Comment: +1 The only solution that doesn't require knowledge about the number of columns.

Comment: you may want to put [ ]+ between the tabs because in one of the comments dr. bunsen mentioned space between tabs is possible

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lane 'print if $#F == 2' INFILE
```

Answer (score 1):

For the specific solution:

```
awk -F'\t' '$2 != ""' input.txt > output.txt
```

For a solution that is generic:

```
awk -F'\t' -vCOLS=3 '{ 
    valid=1; 
    for (i=1; i<=COLS; ++i) { 
        if ($i == "") { 
            valid=0; 
            break; 
        } 
    } 
    if (valid) { 
        print; 
    } 
}' input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -F/\t/ -nle 'print if @F == 3' 1.txt > 2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `awk 'NF == 3' INFILE > OUTFILE` and it will just use white space (tabs, spaces etc..) as the field splitter.